# How do I instantiate a turnContext using the adapter and request as parameters

Tags: botframework

I would like to instantiate a turnContext to be used in integration testing. How would I be able to instantiate one without calling on the processActivity() method of the adapter?

I am looking at the documentation but it shows that I would need the request of the post call as the parameter. I would like my testing to be independant of the post call. I would then assume that I would need to instantiate the request? How would I go about doing so?

[Image of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvSKo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit hard to answer without knowing how you are planning to use the code. That being said, it's not that hard to create a new turnContext and also bypass the processActivity(). Given how you are referencing turnContext and processActivity(), I'm assuming you are using the Node SDK. Implementing in C# wouldn't be too different.

Here are two options, both utilizing the creation of a new adapter, however you can also pass in an already established turnContext, if desired:

1. Use .createContext in server.post in the index.js file, or
2. Maintain the processActivity() method in the server.post. This calls a new "onTurn" method in the bot.js file. In doing so, this allows you to control when and how the new "onTurn" is accessed.

---

Option 1: In the index.js file, you will want to create a new adapter or make a copy of the first depending on your needs:

```js
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: endpointConfig.appId || process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: endpointConfig.appPassword || process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

const newAdapter = adapter;
```

or

```js
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: endpointConfig.appId || process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: endpointConfig.appPassword || process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

const newAdapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: endpointConfig.appId || process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: endpointConfig.appPassword || process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});
```

Include the onTurnError code to catch errors:

```js
// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    await context.sendActivity(`Oops. Something went wrong!`);
};

// Catch-all for errors.
newAdapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    await context.sendActivity(`Oops. Something went wrong!`);
};
```

Then, set the new adapters and create the new turnContext:

```js
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        await bot.onTurn(turnContext);
    });
    newAdapter.createContext(req, res);
});
```

---

Options 2: In the index.js file, building off of the above code, set the adapters to await the individual "onTurn" methods:

```js
// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        await bot.onTurn(turnContext);
    });
    newAdapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        await bot.newOnTurn(turnContext);
    });
});
```

In the bot.js file, you will have your two "onTurn" methods. In this example, the different "onTurn" methods are called based on whether a message is sent or I am deleting user data (I am sending this event via the Emulator => Conversation menu item). What you decide to match on is up to you.

```js
    async newOnTurn(turnContext) {
        if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData) {
            const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(turnContext);

            await dc.context.sendActivity(`Looks like you deleted some user data.`);
        }
    }

    async onTurn(turnContext) {
        if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
            const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(turnContext);

            await dc.context.sendActivity(`Looks like you sent a message.`);
        }
    }
```

Hope of help!

Comment: I figured it out on my own but this helped solidify my understanding of my implementation! Thank you!